# Django: How to write Mixin for queryset for logged in User's data

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am using Generic Class based views for my Project like:

1. ListView (Queryset returning all the objects)
2. DetailView (Queryset for single object)
3. CreateView (Foreignkey data in select boxes)
4. UpdateView (Foreignkey data in select boxes)

How to write a generic Mixin for CBV so that the queryset returns only the data owned by the logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add get_queryset method and loginrequiredmixed like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class ArticleListView(ListView, LoginRequiredMixin):

    model = Article

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Article.objects.filter(publisher=self.request.user) #Just and example, fit it to your problem
```

Comment: I have used this option. I think I am unable to present my problem correctly. I wanted to create a mixin which inherits LoginRequiredMixin and also has functionality of returning the queryset with data owned by the user. If it possible to do it or we have to override get_gueryset() everytime?